Why is this? (searching by filter)
I am searching using a filter composed of several tags, and get empty results:

Why?

Is that asking for a question that has all those tags at once?

@This is what I see after clicking on a custom filter that has all these tags.

Try doing a smaller filter with only (exactly) 6 tags, where you know there should be some results.

@DavidRoberts when I click "watched" filter, which has more tags, the results are found as expected.

Can you give the link to the page that you click on? a screenshot makes it difficult to replicate.

@DavidRoberts yes. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/surreal-numbers+surreal-analysis+hypercomplex-numbers+cardinal-arithmetic+ordinal-computability+ordinal-numbers+ac.commutative-algebra+ra.rings-and-algebras+germs+infinitesimals+divergent-series+divergent-integrals?sort=Newest&uqlId=1421

In that case, this already returns no hits: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/surreal-numbers+surreal-analysis+cardinal-arithmetic with only three tags but if I take off the last tag, [cardinal-arithmetic], I find hits https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/surreal-numbers+surreal-analysis, none of which has [cardinal-arithmetic] as a tag. So I suspect you are implicitly searching for all of those tags with 'AND' not 'OR', in the query.

This search query with just two tags https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/surreal-numbers+cardinal-arithmetic finds one hit, and it doesn't have the tag [surreal-analysis].

@DavidRoberts hmmm, how then can I make the query "or" and what's the purpose of "and" queries over tags at all?

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/surreal-numbers+or+cardinal-arithmetic returns 157 hits, by comparison

From https://mathoverflow.net/help/searching :

OR operator
To combine results from multiple tags, separate the tag names (enclosed in square brackets) with the word "or": [widgets] or [geegaws] returns questions tagged with either tag.


Is there a way to save it as custtom fiter?

Click the filter button and the boolean OR is in/can go in the tag box

@Anixx feel free to mark this as accepted if it solved your problem :-)
